# Show $\lim_{n->\infty} (3\sqrt{n})^{\frac{1}{2n}}=1$ (no L'hopital).

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I need show $\lim_{n->\infty} (3\sqrt{n})^{\frac{1}{2n}}=1$ in a course of Real Analysis, but I can't use derivative. Can you give me a hit?

**I can use:**

- Squeeze theorem
- Convergence with εε-δδ
- Sequential convergence
- The notion of a monotone increasing/decreasing function

Limit laws **no**. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whats sorts of tools do you have access to? Squeeze theorem? Convergence with $\varepsilon$-$\delta$? Sequential convergence? The notion of a monotone increasing/decreasing function? Limit laws? Hints will be much better if we know that information.

Comment: You have reason. I edited now. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for editing that. If you edit one more time to describe what you tried so far and show evidence of your work, you will put yourself in a great position to get some help!

Comment: Can you use the fact that $\log(n)$ grow asymptotically slower than $n$?

Answer (score 1):

For $n$ large enough $3\sqrt{n}<n$, so
$$1\le (3\sqrt{n})^{1/2n}\le n^{1/2n}\le n^{1/n}.$$

On the other hand, for any $\varepsilon>0$,
$$(1+\varepsilon)^n\ge 1+n\varepsilon+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\varepsilon^2\ge n$$
for $n$ large enough.